# Everything I try to write to screen is placed in a text file (PHP)

Tags: php, html, header, writetofile

I'm working on a small piece of code that takes a specific record from an SQL table and places certain columns from that record in a txt file. This works fine, however if I try to echo something to screen, after or before where I fopen the file or fwrite it places that echo in the file as well, even text outside the  is placed in the file.

Here is my current code in its' entirety:

```
Even this outside the PHP is placed in the file.
<?php
echo "Banana";

$orderNo = 3;
    //DB Connect
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('amazondb', $conn); 
    //Open file, select Table
$file = fopen('upload/Order.txt', 'w');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID, PurchaseDate, BuyerName, BuyerPhoneNumber, 
                          BuyerEmail, ShipAddress1,          ShipAddress2, ShipAddress3 
                          FROM imported_orders"); 
    //Loop, input to file
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{   if($row['ID']==($orderNo-1))
{fwrite($file, $row['PurchaseDate'].PHP_EOL .$row['BuyerName']);}
}
fclose($file);
    //Download File
$filename = "upload/Order.txt"; 
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename)); 
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Order.txt'); 
readfile($filename);
?>
```

The above code outputs the following to file:

```
Even this outside the PHP is placed in the file.
Banana2013-03-14
name
```

This is my first time using headers and doing any form of download with PHP, so unsure if that is causing an issue. (I'll be having the download triggered via a HTML form using if isset and the "$orderNo" in the code will be input by the user, not sure if having that done now will solve this issue, though the fact it writes stuff even outside of the PHP worries me)

I open the file, write to the file, then close it, yet the echo before I even open the file is being written to it, same goes for having an echo after I close it.

This is really weird to me and makes no sense, though there is probably a simple 
explanation.

Edit: Only the file downloaded has the extra stuff in it, the file saved on the server is just the data from the table as intended.

Comment: Which file is it being placed in? The file on the server, or the file on the client?

Comment: You realise those headers are sending your content as an application/octet-stream as a file called Order.txt... if you tell a web browser that you're sending it a file rather than simply outputting content, what do you expect? You can't send different things in one request

Comment: It _should_ be put in the file on the client, it shouldn't be in the file on the server.

Comment: You need to understand how HTTP and file downloads work.  This is impossible.

Comment: `Even this outside the PHP is placed in the file, wtf.` is the same as 
`<?php echo 'Even this outside the PHP is placed in the file, wtf.'; ?>`...

Comment: How is this code not complaining about 'output already sent' when he tries to set the headers?

Comment: You're outputting once as text, then trying to output again as something else. You can do one or the other.

Comment: Hi, sorry if the header stuff is extremely wrong, only looked that up about an hour ago, but it worked initially so thought nothing of it
 As for which file its being placed in, not sure why I didn't check earlier but the file saved on the server is correct, only the file which is downloaded to the client is incorrect. Again sorry if my use of headers is terrible and making you sad.

Comment: @xbonez Must be output buffering configured in the ini file.

Comment: @Vereonix What is a file download? The client (your browser) sends a request to your server (you access your PHP script). The server first sends specific HTTP headers, then the file contents. That's it. You cannot have text on the website because there is no such thing as a website in the context of a file download. A website is nothing else than the same request<-->response scheme expect one thing: the headers. You can never have a download and a website (ignore JavaScript for the moment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you use your headers now, all output will be put in the download. If you want a webpage with a link to a download, then create a second page with the link, linking to this page. Then on this page, only echo the data that you want in your file.

Basically what you say with the header is, everything that is sent to the browser for this request will be a file that you want to download.

Comment: Thank you, only now has the penny dropped and I put 2 and 2 together realising every download link I've ever clicked as just essentially been another link wjych just downloads the file